# HP server delayed boot

Tags: storage-area-network, iscsi, vmware-esxi

I'm currently using HP Proliant DL120 G5 servers running VMWare ESXi 4 to run server VM's.  They are connecting to an iSCSI SAN for the shared storage.  I'd like to implement a delayed boot of these hosts servers so that they don't boot up and try to connect to the SAN before the SAN is ready for connections after a power failure. Does anyone know of a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

HP Blades let you do this but the DL100 series don't - what I'd do is delay the startup of Guests, this will allow time for your ESXi host to connect to your storage.

If you really want to delay the OS booting then [HERE](http://vm-help.com/esx/esx3i/boot_delay.php) is a guide of how to do this with ESXi 3-3.5 - not tried it with 4 yet however.

Comment: SYSLINUX. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Many bootloaders have some sort of configuration option that gives a timeout before running the default selection. For lilo this is the `delay=` setting, and for grub this is the `timeout` setting. All you need to do is add it if not present, and give it an appropriately high value. ESXi's bootloader should have a similar option, if it's not one of those two.

Answer (score 0):

This should help: http://www.vm-help.com/esx/esx3i/boot_delay.php